# While click on button from one row of datagrid hide buttons on other row

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one DataGrid and each row of DataGrid contains four buttons.[image]

My screen looks like this. Suppose I click on the start button of Add then I Want all buttons on other rows like Remove, Update and Delete hide until I click on the done button of Add and remove that Add row from DataGrid after processing finished.

My other functionality working fine but the only problem like I click on Add row then also other buttons on other row is clickable so I want to hide that.

Please help me to solve this problem

```
 <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="gridview" Background="#b5d2fc" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Loaded="gridview_Loaded"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn MaxWidth="155" Width="155" Binding="{Binding [Task]}" Header="Name"  />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Start" Content="Play" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="White"  Height="25"  Width="30" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Pause" Content="Pause" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Black" Background="White"  Height="25"  Width="30" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Stop" Content="Stop"   Foreground="Black" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Height="25"  Width="30" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Finish" Content="Finish"   Foreground="Black" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="White" Height="25"  Width="30" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is my xmal code

Comment: You will have to bind properties to your buttons' IsEnabled property, implement INotifyPropertyChanged and change the relevant properties on click of your button as per your logic. I do not think apart from this anyone can help you without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by binding **IsEnabled** property in button control.

xaml snippet:

```
<DataGrid Name="MyGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="MyGrid_Loaded" Height="250"  >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B1">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Start" x:Name="Play" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="20" Width="80"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B2">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Pause"  x:Name="Pause" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="20" Width="80"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B3">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Stop"  x:Name="Stop" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="20" Width="80"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="B4">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="Finish"  x:Name="Finish" Click="Button_Click" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnableButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="20" Width="80"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

xaml.cs

```
                public partial class MainWindow : Window
                {
                    List<TestEnableButton> objtestEnableButton = new List<TestEnableButton>();        
                    public MainWindow()
                    {
                        InitializeComponent();
                        this.DataContext = this;
                    }
                    private void MyGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        objtestEnableButton.Add(new TestEnableButton("A1", true, false));
                        objtestEnableButton.Add(new TestEnableButton("A2", true, false));
                        objtestEnableButton.Add(new TestEnableButton("A3", true, false));
                        objtestEnableButton.Add(new TestEnableButton("A4", true, false));
                        MyGrid.ItemsSource = objtestEnableButton;
                    }

                    bool butFlg = false;
                    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        var getButtonName = (sender as Button).Name;
                        var currentItem = MyGrid.CurrentItem as TestEnableButton;
                        foreach(var items in objtestEnableButton)
                        {
                            if (items.Name == currentItem.Name)
                            {
                                if (getButtonName == "Play")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Let's enjoy music...!)");
                                    butFlg = false;
                                }
                                else if (getButtonName == "Pause")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Pause the music for few minutes...!)"); butFlg = false;
                                }
                                else if (getButtonName == "Stop")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("Stop the music...!)"); butFlg = false;
                                }
                                else if (getButtonName == "Finish")
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("End...!)");                        
                                    items.IsCheckFinish = true;
                                    butFlg = true;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                items.IsEnableButton = false;
                            }
                        }

                        if (butFlg)
                        {
                            var itemsCollection = objtestEnableButton.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCheckFinish == true);
                            objtestEnableButton.ForEach(x => x.IsEnableButton = true);
                            MyGrid.ItemsSource = null;
                            MyGrid.ItemsSource = objtestEnableButton;
                        }            
                    }
                }
                public class TestEnableButton : INotifyPropertyChanged
                {
                    private string _name;
                    public string Name
                    {
                        get { return _name; }
                        set
                        {
                            _name = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                        }
                    }

                    private bool _IsEnableButton;
                    public bool IsEnableButton
                    {
                        get { return _IsEnableButton; }
                        set
                        {
                            _IsEnableButton = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("IsEnableButton");
                        }
                    }

                    private bool _IsCheckFinish;
                    public bool IsCheckFinish
                    {
                        get { return _IsCheckFinish; }
                        set
                        {
                            _IsCheckFinish = value;
                            OnPropertyChanged("IsCheckFinish");
                        }
                    }
                    public TestEnableButton(string name, bool isB, bool isCheck)
                    {
                        Name = name;
                        IsEnableButton = isB;
                        IsCheckFinish = isCheck;
                    }

                    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
                    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
                    {
                        if (PropertyChanged != null)
                        {
                            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your code is working fine but I want to achieve this using my code and I change your code according to my code can you help, please  I upload my code

Comment: Yeah, sure. Share your code. What problem you have faced now ?

Comment: Actually, I am loading data from the database and assign DataTAble as item source if Datagrid

Comment: On your code snippet, you are not set IsEnabled property for button.

Comment: I want values like shown in the image but values come are A1 to A4 and also I am removing from DataTable

Comment: assign the datatable to DataGrid.Itemsource and bind the value for DataGrid column properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193138/discussion-between-user10753256-and-muthukumar-k).

Comment: I update my code but then also I can click multiple row buttons what wrong can you help me out

Comment: I have checked your code snippet, for gridview_Loaded method you have set the itemssource with my collection instead of your DataTable. set the datagrid itemssource propery

Comment: Thank it working fine I make few changes and it works